# How to retrieve the latitude and longitude of a triggered geofence from public List<Geofence> getTriggeringGeofences ()

Tags: android, geofencing

I am new to Android and I am working on a geofencing project.

Is it possible to retrieve the latitude and longitude of a triggered geofence from public List getTriggeringGeofences () ?

I wish to show the triggered locations in a map once we receive the notification alert and user clicks on the notification.On clicking the notificaition a mapActivity with all the triggered geofences pinned should show.
To add a marker i need the LatLong of the triggered location.How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You can get it from the GeofencingEvent.

```
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    GeofencingEvent geofencingEvent = GeofencingEvent.fromIntent(intent);
    if (geofencingEvent.hasError()) {
        //TODO: Error handling

        return;
    }

    Location location = geofencingEvent.getTriggeringLocation();
    double latitude = location.getLatitude();
    double longitude = location.getLongitude();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can get the latitude and longitude from the IntentService geofence event

GeofencingEvent geofencingEvent = GeofencingEvent.fromIntent(intent);

On the intent service is where geofence gets triggered so you will add the pins here:

```
public class GeofenceTransitionsIntentService extends IntentService {

protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    GeofencingEvent geofencingEvent = GeofencingEvent.fromIntent(intent);
    if (geofencingEvent.hasError()) {
        String errorMessage = GeofenceErrorMessages.getErrorString(this,
                geofencingEvent.getErrorCode());
        Log.e(TAG, errorMessage);
        return;
    }

    // Get the transition type.
    int geofenceTransition = geofencingEvent.getGeofenceTransition();

    // Test that the reported transition was of interest.
    if (geofenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER ||
            geofenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT) {

        // Get the geofences that were triggered. A single event can trigger
        // multiple geofences.
        List triggeringGeofences = geofencingEvent.getTriggeringGeofences();

        // Get the transition details as a String.
        String geofenceTransitionDetails = getGeofenceTransitionDetails(
                this,
                geofenceTransition,
                triggeringGeofences
        );

        // Send notification and log the transition details.
        sendNotification(geofenceTransitionDetails);
        Log.i(TAG, geofenceTransitionDetails);
    } else {
        // Log the error.
        Log.e(TAG, getString(R.string.geofence_transition_invalid_type,
                geofenceTransition));
    }
}
```

Android official documentation has a nice tutorial on implementing geofencing:

https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html

Comment: Yes i used the same method.I wanted to know if we can extract the latitude and logitude alone from each geofence.
like for example: geofence.getRequestId() returns the request id alone.
Similar way can we extract latlong from geofence logged below:

Geofence[CIRCLE id:satellite township transitions:1 10.006100, 76.331200 1000m, resp=0s, dwell=-1ms, @187017824]

I need the  transitions:1 10.006100, 76.331200 part alone.